# Edit the Barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I've created a barplot and I want to make some changes in the layout. I've tried a couple of things but I want to do the following:

1. Change the Y-axis interval from 0 - 50%
2. Make the size of the letters which present the percentage within the bars smaller
3. Remove the gray background and change it for a white one

The plot can be found here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDdnF.png)

The code I provided is:

```
beoordeling <- ggplot(data=etadam, aes(x = beoordeling)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), colour = "black", width = 0.6, fill = '#ffd308') +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0,2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 1)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = 'percentage', title = 'Welk cijfer geven jullie de examentraining?', subtitle = 'N = 400 | Alle trainingen', caption = 'Leren voor de Toekomst©')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
beoordeling <- ggplot(data=etadam, aes(x = beoordeling)) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), colour = "black", width = 0.6, fill = '#ffd308') +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0,2, size = 2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.5), expand = c(0,0),labels = percent) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 1)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = 'percentage', title = 'Welk cijfer geven jullie de examentraining?', subtitle = 'N = 400 | Alle trainingen', caption = 'Leren voor de Toekomst©')
```

1. add `limits = c(0,0.5)` and if you wish `expand = c(0,0)` inside `scale_y_continuous()`.
2. Change `size` in `geom_text()`. I set it to 2 at the moment
3. Use `theme_minimal()`, `theme_classic()` or `theme_light()`. See [ggplot themes](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html)